# How to define function for scipy.optimize.curve_fit?

Tags: scipy, curve-fitting

I have been trying to make a curve fit for my histogram using scipy.optimize.curve_fit. Here is the sample code I am working on:

```
def gaussian(x,a,b,c):
    return a * exp(-(x - b)**2 / c**2) 

def curvefit(gaussian, x, y,sigma):
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(gaussian, x, y, p0 = [1, mean, sigma])
    image = plt.plot(x, gauss_function(x, *popt), label='fit')
```

Where x is the binned x values (output from my histogram), y is the weight corresponding to those binned x (output from histogram as well). While running the code, I keep getting an error:

```
global name 'a' is not defined
```

And i understand why this error arouse but cannot find a way to fix it. Since curve_fit has the 1st parameter as a callable function, I don't know how to specify that in Python (seems like the program is reading the output of my gaussian function as a value). Thank you very much.

Comment: When I try this, I need to define `mean` or pass it as a parameter to `curvefit`, or else I get an error that `mean` is undefined. Have you tried that? Also, is `gauss_function` supposed to be `gaussian`?

Comment: Please provide a complete working example that produces your error.

Answer (score 0):

Although without a full working example this is impossible to answer, I suffered a lot from similar problems when working with `scipy`. The code becomes quite obscure quite fast.

I therefore think you would be helped by using the [`symfit`](http://symfit.readthedocs.org/) package. Full disclaimer: I build that package to make fitting more pythonic after rage quitting `scipy` for the n-th time.

Your problem would look like this:

```py
from symfit import Parameter, Variable, Fit, exp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = Variable()
A = Parameter()
sig = Parameter(value=1.4, min=1.0, max=2.0)
x0 = Parameter(value=15.0, min=0.0)
# Gaussian distrubution
model = A * exp(-((x - x0)**2/(2 * sig**2)))

fit = Fit(model, xdata, ydata)
fit_result = fit.execute()

y = model(x=xdata, **fit_result.params)
plt.plot(xdata, ydata)
plt.plot(xdata, y)
plt.show()
```

I think this will make your life easier because I went through all the pain of wrapping `curve_fit` for you. If you really want to use `curve_fit` you'll have to be more specific.